# OKHTTP request not the same as Postman request

Tags: java, android, okhttp

When trying to make a request to a server using the Okhttp library in an android environment it doesn't do the same as the (what I think) same call in Postman (The code was copied from Postman to the android classes).

Code:

```
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            String content = "userid=userID&passwd=passWord&__CSRFToken__=" + token + "&do=scplogin";
            Log.i("Content", content);
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, content);
            Request loginRequest = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(loginURL)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .build();

Response loginResponce = client.newCall(loginRequest).execute();
```

And this is a screenshot of the body in Postman:

[image]

Edit: problem is that when using the call in the android environment the server replies that the CSRF token is not valid while it should be as i am using the same methods of getting that token for both the Postman call and the call in android

Comment: Suggest you dig more into how you get the CSRF token, and possibly whether one of the headers is related.  If there's anything that looks like a session id, you may need to preserve and pass that one too.  It may be worth installing an intercepting proxy such as Fiddler - tell your Android app to use the address of Fiddler on your dev machine, and tell Fiddler to forward those requests to the API endpoint.

Comment: better use volley stringrequest for such tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @GregHNZ said it was a problem with sessions. The server responded with a cookie which i did not think about before now. Bij adding the given Cookie to the correct header the responce was correct.